# arara Failing on Validating Directory

Tags: pdftex, arara, makefile

## Problem

I am trying to switch over to using `arara` instead of a very complex `makefile`.  I am running into the a problem where `arara` is telling me that a directory is invalid and that I need to fix it. The main problem I have is that I cannot figure out *which* directory is invalid. I help configuring the tool to tell me exactly which line of my `main.tex` file (or whatever file it is) that is causing `arara` to stop.

## Error Log

```
Welcome to arara 7.0.3!
-----------------------------------------------------------------
20 Jun 2022 15:13:11.594 DEBUG - 
::: arara @ D:\Program Files\MiKTeX\scripts\arara
::: Java 17.0.1, Oracle Corporation
::: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1
::: Windows 10, amd64, 10.0
::: user.home @ C:\Users\me
::: CF @ [none]
-----------------------------------------------------------------
20 Jun 2022 15:13:11.606 INFO  - Processing "main.tex" (size: 2.9 kB, last modified: 2022-06-20 19:13:08), please wait.
20 Jun 2022 15:13:11.625 INFO  - I found a potential pattern in line 1: pdflatex { shell: yes, interaction: nonstopmode }
20 Jun 2022 15:13:11.625 INFO  - I found a potential pattern in line 2: biber
20 Jun 2022 15:13:11.626 INFO  - I found a potential pattern in line 3: makeglossaries
20 Jun 2022 15:13:11.626 INFO  - I found a potential pattern in line 4: pdflatex { shell: yes, interaction: nonstopmode }
20 Jun 2022 15:13:11.626 INFO  - I found a potential pattern in line 5: pdflatex { shell: yes, interaction: nonstopmode }
20 Jun 2022 15:13:11.627 ERROR - I spotted an invalid directive (1) in the provided file. Make sure to fix the directive and try again.
20 Jun 2022 15:13:11.629 INFO  - Total: 0.305 seconds
```

## Part of `main.tex`

```
% arara: pdflatex { shell: yes, interaction: nonstopmode } 
% arara: biber
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex { shell: yes, interaction: nonstopmode }
% arara: pdflatex { shell: yes, interaction: nonstopmode }


\documentclass[
  12pt,
  % final, % any \todo{<x>} commands are removed
  % print, % removes link color for print version
  % ngerman, % to switch language to German 
  english, % to switch language to English 
  nonumberlist % Removes numbering on the glossaries itself
]{thesis}
```

Comment: Looks like the error message is about a _directive_ and not a _directory_.

Comment: You are missing colons before the options in braces. Btw: It tells you that the error is in directive 1, so it is quite specific.

Comment: TeXnician. Yeah... that seems to have done it. I really should stop writing at all hours. If you want, make a reply so I can mark it answered.

Comment: Have done so :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing colons in the *directives* (not directories):

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: yes, interaction: nonstopmode } 
% arara: biber
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: yes, interaction: nonstopmode }
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: yes, interaction: nonstopmode }
```